# How can I make ''html_attr("href")'' return a complete link?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Ok so first off here is my code.

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(RSelenium)
library(tidyverse)
library(httr2)

url \<- "https://www.congress.gov/congressional-record/50th-congress/browse-by-date"
target_page \<- read_html(url)

x <- GET(url, add_headers('user-agent' = 'Gov employment data scraper (smtorres@ucla.edu)'))
target_page <- x %>% read_html(url)
target_page

driver <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox",
               chromever = NULL)
remote_driver <- driver[["client"]]
remote_driver$open()
remote_driver$navigate(url)
remote_driver$getTitle()

html_source <- remote_driver$getPageSource()
target_page <- read_html(html_source[[1]])

target_page

tab = html_nodes(target_page, xpath='//*[@id="innerbox_20-3"]')
daylinks <- tab %>% html_nodes("a")
links <- daylinks %>% html_attr("href")

links
```

I am trying to figure out how to get this line:

```
links <- daylinks %>% html_attr("href")
```

to create a list of links but it keeps returning things like
"/bound-congressional-record/1889/03/02/senate-section"
instead of
'https://www.congress.gov/bound-congressional-record/1889/03/02/senate-section'

How can I fix this?????
Also if possible is there an easy way to open the links so that I can start scraping those pages as well?

Thank you!

Comment: A shortcut might be: `paste0("https://www.congress.gov", daylinks %>% html_attr("href"))`

Comment: Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, this can be avoided with a simple "trick":

```r
paste0("https://www.congress.gov", daylinks %>% html_attr("href"))
```